# Return row with missing values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view with the following columns :

`OLD_RUN_ID | NEW_RUN_ID | IND_ID | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE`

This view has entries for `NEW_RUN_ID = 260`, and has no entry for `OLD_RUN_ID = 257`.

Is there a query to have something like that :

```
OLD_RUN_ID | NEW_RUN_ID | IND_ID | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE
257        | 260        | 1      | (null)    | 68726
257        | 260        | 2      | (null)    | 6847864
```

I've tried so far :

```
select distinct d.* from v_audit d
full join v_audit dd on d.ind_id = dd.ind_id
WHERE d.old_run_id = 260
AND dd.new_run_id = 257;
```

But no rows were returned.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding. If there is "no entry for OLD_RUN_ID = 257", how would any such record exist in your result?

Comment: Is this just a type?  Do you want WHERE d.new_run_id = 260
AND dd.old_run_id = 257;  ?

Comment: If your question is "can oracle somehow guess a replacement value for a column of a non existing row by scanning the where clause for the expected value", then the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

We left join using the old ID and if it's not present it's omitted.

```
select '257' as OLD_RUN_ID, D.New_Run_ID, D.Ind_ID, DD.Old_Value, D.new_value
from v_audit d
LEFT join v_audit dd 
  on d.ind_id = dd.ind_id
  AND dd.new_run_id = 257
WHERE d.old_run_id = 260 ;
```

Now if either could be null then...

```
select '257' as OLD_RUN_ID, '260' as New_Run_ID, D.Ind_ID, DD.Old_Value, D.new_value
from v_audit d
FULL OUTER join v_audit dd 
  on d.ind_id = dd.ind_id
  AND dd.new_run_id = 257
  and d.old_run_id = 260 ;
```

The issue is that the limits are being applied after the join, you want them to occur before the join